# Moving int values from an array to another one

Tags: javascript, arrays, int, move

I started learning js so i'm fairly new to this. My issue is:
I have an array, for example:

```
var firstArray = [1, 2, "Blue", "Yellow", 5, "Orange"];
```

And then i need to make a new array (lets say `secondArray`) in which you will move all the *int* values from the `firstArray`. After some research i found that `isNaN` would be what i need. Could someone try and explain me how would i make this happen?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> Use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), *The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.*

```js
var firstArray = [1, 2, "Blue", "Yellow", 5, "Orange"];
var op = firstArray.filter(Number);
console.log(op);
```

In every iteration, each item will be passed through `Number`, values which can not be converted to `Number` will return `NaN` which is `falsey` value and it will be excluded.

---

**Edit:** As commented by [*canon*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/621962/canon), `.filter(Number)` will also discard `0` if exists in array because `Number(0) === 0 ==> "falsey value"`

If you want to keep `0` value in filtered-array, use `isNaN(Number(item))` in `Test Function`

```js
var firstArray = [1, 2, "Blue", "Yellow", 5, "Orange", 0];
var op = firstArray.filter(function(item) {
  return !isNaN(Number(item));
});
console.log(op);
```

Comment: Whoa now, this is way too efficient..This needs some more jQuery and a few more loops. Very slick! :)

Comment: Normally I wouldn't vote on an answer to a close-vote question, but +1 because console.js TIL. That is so cool

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you for helping making this issue seem so simple to solve.

Comment: I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_

Comment: @user3477993 It works fine. But ask him how it would exclude the strings while filtering.  rayon: I know what is happening under the hood. But it would be good for future visitors, if you add few details of it in your answer.

Comment: This filtration method will discard zeros. While that's not a problem for the sample values specified, future visitors may be surprised by that behavior.

Comment: @canon, That was really helpful and valid point! I have updated the post.. Any suggestions/corrections are welcome!

Comment: @SterlingArcher that's a pity. I swear I promoted it in the javascript room for months. :/

Answer (score 0):

The method above is cooler and better for sure! Here it is using the isNaN like you asked for:

Using isNaN:
[JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/majana/2/edit?js,console)

```
function cut(arr){
  var ints = [];
  var others = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (isNaN(arr[i])) {
      others.push(arr[i]);
    } else {
      ints.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  console.log(others);
  console.log(ints);
}
```